# Assigning Multiple Customer Groups to Customers

Tags: magento2.3, catalog-price-rules, magento2-enterprise

I'm working on a Magento 2 Commerce project at the moment that has data ready to be imported that has thousands of price rules.

The issue I have currently is that there are customer groups in their system that have more than one price group associated with it.

For example, they have a customer price list group called '03', and within that they have price codes called '03Q1', '03Q2', '03Q3', etc.

Therefore, the only way we could do this within Magento is to create each variation as a customer group. The issue with that is because there are so many (around 4500), this would be impractical to maintain.

Another issue we found was that within their price data, they have examples where one product appears in more than one price group, and the customer appears in more than one price groups.

In Magento, advanced pricing is handled by customer groups, and we know that you can't have a customer that belongs to more than one customer group.

As such, are they any plugins out there that might be able to assist with this issue and make admin work a lot easier to manage ? We tried Customer Segmentation but you can't use that for product price rules, only cart price rules.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Many thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

You can add one customer attribute to manage Q1, Q2, Q3 value and do filter with both value customer group and custom attribute.

ex: customer group value: 03  custom attribute value: Q1 so  you will get 03Q1

You need to do custom code. To manage you can use plugging or observe.

hope it will help you!!!